# Searching field types set to VMG Chosen Member in the Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, vmg-chosen-member

I'm using VMG Chosen Member as a Field Type so administrators can easily add Members of a custom Member Group 'Customers' to different Channel Entries.

This is fine, but when in the Control Panel I cannot search or filter on this Field Type. I have set the VMG Chosen Member (Customer) to be searchable but this doesn't make a difference.

This is a major issue for my client, as they will need to be able to search and filter entries in the CP by 'Customer'.

Does anyone know if this is an actual issue or something else I could do to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because of how VMG Chosen Member stores the member data in the exp_channel_data table, not in a full text format. Unfortunately this isn't an issue with the add-on, it's just how it works.

What you may be able to do is use the [Zenbu](http://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu) addon, which overrides the Edit screen. You could then build a custom extension that searches the correct field from the exp_members table, rather than the default exp_channel_data field.

If you haven't worked with extensions before, this wouldn't quite be trivial to do, but it's the only option I can think of.

Comment: That's a real shame, but thanks for letting me know Jeremy.

I've never written any custom extensions and I suspect that will be beyond my abilities tbh. More of a designers than developer.